# How to solve this array query/ update problem?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given array "A" of size N, and U updates, in each update there are three integers l,r,x means update all A[i], l<=i<=r with min(A[i],x). After all the updates, print the final array "A".

Constraints: 1<=A[i],x<=1000000 ;

1<=U,N<=100005 ;

1<=l,r<=N

Unable to find any O(ulogn) solution.

Comment: segment tree with lazy propagation will get `O(nlogn)`

Comment: But I think lazy propagation cannot be applied as it can only be applied when you have to update all values in a range = x , or add all values in a range with x .  Here, only those values in the range needs to be changed whose A[i]>x, as new value = min(A[i],x) ,  for l<=i<=r .

Comment: The complexity you ask for does not depend on U at all, this does make sense to me, could you clarify / update?

Comment: @RelaxRelaxation if A[i] is < x, doing A[i] = min(x,A[i]) wont ruin anything so lazy proapgation can be used

Comment: I have assumed N=U, if each update can be done in log(N), then it seems to be efficient to me. (NlogN) or (UlogN), both are pretty much similar...

Comment: @Photon can you provide some small code snippet for update operation on this case using lazy propagation, it will be helpful . I have my code snippet here :

Comment: Please use the "edit" option to update your question with the assumption of n==u.

Comment: @Photon This is my code which finds minimum number in a range and also, updates all a[i] = x in a given range [l,r] .  What changes do I need to make in update function(line-26) so it can also solve the above problem of a[i]=min(x,a[i]). Thanks.!

Comment: https://ideone.com/l2SYtc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with segment tree using lazy propagation.

- Important observation: doing some multiple updates for `A[i] = min(A[i], x)` can be reduced to 1 update having lowest `x` value
- Another observation if `A[i] < x` doing update `A[i] = min(A[i], x)` does not ruin the result

Sample code (C++):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define oo 0x3f3f3f3f

struct node {
    int val;
    int lazy = oo;
};

node seg[4*100001];
int A[100001];

void build(int c, int l, int r)
{
    if(l==r)
    {
        seg[c].val = A[r];
        return;
    }
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    build(2*c,l,m);
    build(2*c+1,m+1,r);
    seg[c].val=min(seg[2*c].val,seg[2*c+1].val);
}

void Lazy(int c, int l, int r)
{
    seg[c].val = min(seg[c].val, seg[c].lazy);
    if(l!=r)
    {
        seg[2*c].lazy=min(seg[2*c].lazy, seg[c].lazy);
        seg[2*c+1].lazy=min(seg[2*c+1].lazy, seg[c].lazy);
    }
    seg[c].lazy=oo;
}

void Update(int c, int l, int r, int L, int R, int x)
{
    Lazy(c,l,r);
    if(l > r || l > R || r < L)return;
    if(l >= L && r <=R)
    {
        seg[c].lazy = x;
        Lazy(c,l,r);
        return;
    }
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    Update(2*c,l,m,L,R,x);
    Update(2*c+1,m+1,r,L,R,x);
}

int Get(int c, int l, int r, int pos)
{
    Lazy(c,l,r);
    if(l==r)return seg[c].val;
    int m = (l+r)/2;
    if(pos <= m)return Get(2*c,l,m,pos);
    return Get(2*c+1,m+1,r,pos);
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)A[i]=i;
    build(1,1,10);
    Update(1,1,10,2,5,2);
    Update(1,1,10,3,7,1);
    Update(1,1,10,7,9,0);
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)cout<<Get(1,1,10,i)<<" ";
}
```